# Calling country API returns whole database in spring boot instead of only countries

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, service, controller

I want to return only countries from country table by calling an API in spring boot. But it returns all the countries along with all the states and cities related with every country and city in the world. Here's my code.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    @Column (name = "countryid")
    private String countryId;
    @Column (name = "country")
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<State>states = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, String> {
}
```

```
@Service
public class CountryService {
    @Autowired
    CountryRepository countryRepository;

    public List<Country> getallCountries(){

        return countryRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/country")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080", allowCredentials = "true")

public class CountryController {
    @Autowired
    CountryService countryService;

    @GetMapping
    List<Country> getAllCountries(){

        return  countryService.getallCountries();
    }
}
```

When I called **http://localhost:8080/country**, it returned the **whole database**.

This is my country table and I want to return only country column by calling the api above. How to do that?

| countryid | country |
| --- | --- |
| BRA | Brazil |
| CHN | China |
| IND | India |
| USA | USA |

Comment: Research projections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Mahadi Hasan I've checked your code.

First of all, you should write some REST methods solving your problem for the web application:

```
@GetMapping("/countries")
public List<CountryView> getAllCountries()
{
    ...
}

@GetMapping("/countries/{id}/states")
public List<StateView> getStatesByCountry(@PathVariable("id") String countryId)
{
    ...
}

@GetMapping("/states/{id}/cities")
public List<CityView> getCitiesByCountry(@PathVariable("id") Long stateId)
{
    ...
}
```

So, now we know what we want from the database. We could use projections to exactly fetch this data. Projections are a means to directly wrap the results from queries into specialized DTOs.

Finally I found a proper solution:

## Repository methods:

```
List<CountryView> findAllBy(); // The 'By' is necessary to differentiate from findAll()

List<StateView> findByCountry_countryId(String id); // The _ is necessary to prevent from searching a property countryCountryId. We want country.countrId instead.

List<CityView> findByState_stateId(Long id); // Same as above here
```

First I tried with unidirectional relationships. This led to a somewhat inefficient approach because I had to write a query with a JOIN. I found out that this works better with bidirectional relationships as you have foreseen in your entities already.

## Projections

```
public interface CountryView {
    String getCountryId();
    String getCountry();
}

public interface StateView {
    Long getStateId();
    String getState();
}

public interface CityView {
    Long getCiyId();
    String getCity();
}
```

Now you can fill in the repository calls into the controller code. I omit the service layer here. You'll manage this for your own.

If you enable SQL logging you'll see that you get simple efficient queries.

Next you should consider to use the same name and type for your ids and names. If your entities would each have a Long id and String name, you could go with a single projection.

Comment: Hello @Karsten, this is for dependent dropdown. 
First dropdown will give me the list of all countries. Upon selection, for example, USA,
2nd dropdown will return a list of all states of USA. Now let's select NY,
3rd dropdown will return all the cities of NY. 

So, in order to return the list of all countries, can it be done without writing a query? 

Honestly speaking, I am a fresher in spring boot and find it pretty complex about what code to write to where. I will be happy if you guide me through this process.

Comment: To make this easy for you, here is my github link https://github.com/Mahadijava/my_world.  I've also added the database file name myworld.sql.  Could you please see the code and help me for a better solution?

Comment: return countryService.getCountries().stream().map(Country::getName).toList(); and the other snippet are really bad ideas: you are querying several (all!) db tables where instead it should be just a select on one table.

Comment: I know, but it would be the easiest solution for this problem.

Comment: @Karsten, I am so glad with your help. But there's something needs clarification. Could you please elaborate the code about when to use _ and why? Why cannot I write **findByCountryId** ?
 `List<StateView> findByCountry_countryId(String id); // The _ is necessary to prevent from searching a property countryCountryId. We want country.countrId instead.`

Comment: This is because countryId isn't a direct property of State. Its a nested property: country.countryId. Maybe the method will work as findByCountryCountryId too, but to ensure spring data jpa is aware of being countryId a nested property you add a _.